# Windows Server 2008 R2: Deleted Objects show as Lingering Objects

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008

> DC1.Forest.Domain.com
>
> > DC2.Child.Domain.com

When checking DC2 for Lingering Objects (for the Forest.Domain.com partition) it shows 100s of objects all in CN=Deleted Objects.

I don't understand what it means, if an object is deleted from DC1, its deletion attribute is replicated to DC2 (and tombstoned on both locations), in which scenario will the deleted object display as a Lingering Object on DC2?

Bonus question: Are tombstoned objects still replicate during AD replication?

Comment: An object is not a lingering object simply because it exists in Deleted Objects. If you have lingering objects, replication will be blocked. If replication is working, there aren't any lingering objects.

Comment: Using the LOL tool I see 100s of Lingering Objects, and replication is working fine. Strict Replication Consistency is enabled. And 'allow replication with divergent and corrupt partner' is disabled.

Comment: I think it is possible replication would be ok if the DC is not attempting to replicate them to another DC. Sounds like you just need to use LOL to remove them.

Comment: Sure I can remove them. I am trying to understand why "CN=Deleted Objects" objects show as lingering objects.

Comment: Have you confirmed they aren't false positives?